# Using Javascript in HTML returning false even if the condition is true

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Javascript in HTML to return a popup error if the input in the searchbar is not 'Dog'. However, it still shows the popup error when the input is 'Dog'.

```
 <div class="search" >

    <input type="text" name="s" 
      <a href="/redirect.php">
    <button id="find" type="submit" 
    onclick="javascript: if(document.getElementById('find').value!='Dog') 
    {
        alert('This animal does not exist in the system, try another one...');
        return false;
    }">&nbsp;</button>
  </div>
```

The code is supposed to go to redirect.php if the input in the searchbar is 'dog'. Where am I going wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted correct html?

Comment: Yep, I'm sure. There were two lines related to <div> that I left out, but they had more to do with the CSS styling and not the functionality itself. Anyhow, I'll add them in by editing...

Comment: I was referring to incomplete tag <input type="text" name="s" :-)

Comment: Something seems to be missing.  In the posted HTML, there is no element with id 'find'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="search" >
    <input type="text" id="find" name="s" />
    <a href="/redirect.php">
    <button  type="submit" 
    onclick="javascript: if(document.getElementById('find').value!='Dog') {
        alert('This animal does not exist in the system, try another one...');
        return false;
    }">&nbsp;</button>
</div>
```

### Update:

The reason why it wasn't working before was because the button element had the ***find*** id instead of the text field.